# How can I get videos based on user genre?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

As you can see in my definition below. User can have one or many videos. A user can have one genre.

How can I list videos based on a specific genre?

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  references_many :videos
  referenced_in :genre

  ....
end

class Video 
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  referenced_in :user
  ....
end

class Genre
  include Mongoid::Document

  references_one :user
  ....
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I decided to add a genre cache column on the document. This means I've got a genre column in the User collection and Video collection

Answer (score 0):

You need to do several requests.

```
list_your_want = Genre.all.inject({}) do |result, genre|
  result[genre.name] = genre.user.videos
  result
end
```

Comment: Im not trying to get genres. I need the videos based on a genre

Comment: You have an hash with genre in key and list of video of this genre in value. You can't get have better with your schema

Comment: How else would you design this type of schema? Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to suggest in your code snippet above. In any case, your code returns: undefined method `videos' for []:Array

Comment: if you have some genre without user you have error report in previous. If you want modify your schema, add some link between your genre and video without need to throw by user